# Switch item placed in wrong place in Menu

Tags: android, menu

I try to add a `Switch` item in the menu. It isn't placed under all items but on Action Bar.
Here is my code:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:title="@string/help" />

    <item
        android:title="Switch1"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Here You can see how it looks in an XML file (up) and in emulator (down).
[image]

Is there any way to place this `Switch` item under the `Help` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to add a Switch button in the sub menu.

However you can custom your own popup and do whatever you want.

Comment: Okay, so I 'll just use ` android:checkable="true"`. Works in the same way as `Switch` but I think `Switch` looks better